# Vim Search and Replace Efficiency

Tags: vim, replace

Often I want to search and replace in vim like this:

```
:%s/<search_pattern>/<search_pattern>_foo/g
```

Is there a way to make this syntax more efficient so that I can reference `<search_pattern>` in the replace value?  I'm thinking it would be something similar to back referencing by group name/number, but I can't find any docs on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `&` character to represent the matched pattern in the replacement:

```
:%s/<search_pattern>/&_foo/g
```

Alternately you can use `\0`, which is a back-reference for the whole matched pattern, and so may be easier to remember:

```
:%s/<search_pattern>/\0_foo/g
```

See `:help sub-replace-special`

And, thanks to [@kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348785/kev), you can force an empty pattern at the end of your search string using `\zs`, to be replaced by __foo_ in the replacement:

```
:%s/<search_pattern>\zs/_foo/g
```

This means: replace the end of the search string with __foo_.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `&` for the entire search pattern, or you can use groups to match a section of the pattern. Using `&`:

```
:%s/<search_pattern>/&_foo/g
```

This would accomplish what you're looking for. If you need something a little more complex use groups. To make a group, surround part of the search pattern with (escaped) parenthesis. You can then reference that with `\n`, where `n` is the group number. An example would explain it better.

You have the following file:

```
bread,butter,bread,bread,bread,butter,butter,etc
```

You want to change any instance of `bread,butter` to `bread and butter`:

```
:%s/\(bread\),\(butter\)/\1 and \2/g
```